# Is it possible to use ActiveMQ for publish/subscribe messaging

Tags: activemq-classic, broker

I am very much new to activemq. I was trying to use activemq broker for subscribe/publish messages. But as for lack of experience I have no idea how to do it or if its really possible to do it. I googled a lot but unfortunately there is no suitable example for this type of functionality. So I was hoping may be someone here can put some light on it. Can any one here can give me some example of how to do it? or may be some link to online documentation. I have already tried apache activemq broker documentation. But it was not helpful, or may be I dont have that much experience to take help from it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in is done using topics. The reason that you haven't necessarily seen a description of it on the ActiveMQ site is that it's a foundational thing that is assumed that readers know about.

If you are looking at an introduction into messaging using Java, the best place is [Oracle's JMS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JMS.html). Afterwards take a look at the code in the `examples` directory of an ActiveMQ installation. Alternatively, [ActiveMQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/snyder/) is a great book to get you heading in the right direction.

If you are using a language other than Java, ActiveMQ [supports](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) the [STOMP protocol](http://stomp.github.com/) for which there are a large number of [implementations](http://stomp.github.com/implementations.html) in various languages.

Hope that helps.